# Scala and Tomcat -> NoClassDefFound Stringbuilder?

Tags: scala, servlets, tomcat6

when I run my scala application under tomcat, I am unable to do basic string concatenation, and I get an error stating that no class definition was found for StringBuilder. I'm running under windows 7 (development) and ubuntu (production), and I don't believe that java 1.4.x JDK or JRE has ever been insalled on either system.

Any idea why

```
val html = "<p>" + request.getParameter("myParam") + "</p>"
```

isn't working?

This is rather frustrating.

Comment: I suspect that (sorry that I am wrong), Scala using StringBuilder which was added since 1.5 but Tomcat may only run 1.4 code (The same way J2ME run 1.3 code). You don't need to install 1.4 JDK, any of Sun JDK (perhaps any JDK) can be used for older java version. In this case, tomcat run your code like 1.4 code which does not have StringBuilder.

Comment: A quick look around shows that people seems to have similar problem: http://www.nabble.com/Newbie-problem-working-with-JDK-1.4-java.util.Map-from-Scala-td17152964.html . Unfortunately, there seems to have no solution yet.

Comment: Tomcat is definitely pointing to the jdk6 jre in catalina.sh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the missing class `scala.StringBuilder` or the `StringBuilder` in `java.lang`? If the former, it sounds a lot like you are running the app without the `scala-library.jar` scala library, which should be added to the runtime classpath.

Comment: I couldn't get any scala application to run until I included the scala-library jar in the tomcat libs directory. Are you saying that there's more to library setup than that? What am I missing?

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question whether you are trying to run this under JDK1.4 or 1.5. Which one are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried compiling with `-target:jvm-1.4`?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but why should I need to do this? I've had regular java apps running on 1.5 under tomcat.

Comment: If tomcat is running jvm 1.4, as suggested by others, this should help.

Comment: Why would tomcat be running jvm 1.4? I don't want it to be running jvm 1.4!